# Allow Linking to draft posts from classic editor

Tags: links, editor, draft

I often work with content that has NDA dates applied to it. So i could have a dozen articles ready to publish but need to wait until a specific date to do so. It would be so handy if i could do all of my internal linking between these draft posts in advance so i dont have to publish them all and then go back and link them all again.

I cant seem to find anyway to make the classic editor also include draft posts when you are using the linking tool.